# When do all annihilators of primitive idempotents intersect in {0}?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

maybe this is silly but:

for which class of rings (or commutative rings) R may I write

An element a of R is zero iff
for every primitive idempotent e, ea is zero

?

That is, primitive idempotents "generate R" in a very loose sense, without requiring that 1 be sum of them. Maybe this is always?

Comment: I realized this can't be always (and thus the quesion is not silly) because for the existence of primitive idempotents we need the descending chain condition on principal idempotent-generated ideals. Thus, Artiniannes wiil do. But I am looking for a weaker condition. Whoever may help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is enough to assume that $R$ is left or right noetherian.

If $R$ is left or right noetherian then $R$ is "orthogonally finite" meaning that it does not have an infinite set of mutually orthogonal idempotents. (An immediate application of the ACC.)

If $R$ is orthogonally finite then $R$ has a complete set of primitive idempotents, i.e. $1_R$ can be written as a sum of mutually orthogonal primitive idempotents. (Prove it inductively, for example.) Your condition immediately follows from the existence of this complete set of primitive idempotents.